# Command line tool to generate client code in C# (target = .Net Framework 4.8) for an Open API

Tags: c#, openapi, openapi-generator, .net-4.8, openapi-generator-cli

Are there any command line tool/utility that we can use to generate C# code/file (target = .Net Framework 4.8) for an Open API?

I have explored AutoRest, but it generates code targeting .NET Core/.NET 5/.NET 6

I have explored OData Client Connected Service in Visual Studio. It does generate C# code for .NET Framework. The OData-CLI however, does not generate for C# .NET Framework, but for .NET Core/.NET 5/.NET 6).

Comment: did you manage to find a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OpenAPI Generator CLI tool, it has a generator called csharp-netcore, but you can configure the target framework to .net 4.8 ([link](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/csharp-netcore))

`openapi-generator-cli generate -i your-input-api.json -g csharp-netcore -o .\output --additional-properties=targetFramework=net48`

There is a bunch of configuration options. You can save them in a json file, like so:

`dotnetconfig.json`

```json
    {
        "targetFramework":"net48",
        "packageName":"My.Api.Name"
    }
```

Then use the command like so:
`openapi-generator-cli generate -i your-input-api.json -g csharp-netcore -o /output -c dotnetconfig.json`

### Update

The csharp-netcore generator is not available anymore. But you can use [csharp generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/csharp) instead.

Command:
`openapi-generator-cli generate -i your-input-api.json -g csharp -o output -c config.json`